# Stacking/chaining CNNs for different use cases

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So I'm getting more and more into deep learning using CNNs.

I was wondering if there are examples of "chained" (I don't know what the correct term would be) CNNs - what I mean by that is, using e.g. a first CNN to perform a semantic segmentation task while using its output as input for a second CNN which for example performs a classification task.

My questions would be:

What is the correct term for this sequential use of neural networks?

Is there a way to pack multiple networks into one "big" network which can be trained in one a single step instead of training 2 models and combining them.

Also if anyone could maybe provide a link so I could read about that kind of stuff, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequential use of independent neural networks can have different interpretations:

1. The first model may be viewed as a [feature extractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) and the second one is a [classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification).
2. It may be viewed as a special case of [stacking (stacked generalization)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Stacking) with a single model on the first level.

It is a common practice in deep learning to chain multiple models together and train them jointly. Usually it calls **end-to-end learning**. Please see the answer about it: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/16575/what-does-end-to-end-training-mean

[image]